# "Но не любил в ответ его никто" what does this exactly mean?

Tags: перевод

Can someone give me a certain question? please?
I believe it's something like "but he is not love back by nobody"
But I'm not sure.

Comment: The word ordering is quite unusual for normal speech. Moreover, the sentence is 5-iambus. Is this a line from poem? If it's a well-known one, you should also give its title etc.

Answer (score 4):

First, lets try to change this sentence to "default" order of words.
(Current order is correct, it is just emphasizing one of words)

The subject is "никто" - *nobody*. Subject should be in the nominative case.
The verb is "не любил" - *did not love*. It is active case.
The verb has the direct object "его" - *him* (*did not love him*)
And there is the adverbial phrase "в ответ" - *back*.

We get

> Но никто не любил его в ответ.
>   *Nobody loved him back.*

Russian has one more negation then English in sentences with negative pronouns, such as *nobody, nowhere, nothing*.

Changing the order of words in Russian emphasizes some of them. It also can be used in poetry.

> Но не любил в ответ его *никто*.

(He loved and cared for a lot of people, but *nobody* loved him back)

Comment: в ответ - in return

Answer (score 0):

I think, the previous context assumes he was making some good things. But he has not get recognition (love) from anybody for that.

So the translation can be "But he haven't get any regards in return".